# How can I move alert message div out of <form> tag

Tags: javascript, html, forms, alert, message

I am trying a code where there is a form to accept email address for newsletter subscription;

When the alert message is displayed on empty field or invalid email submit, the alert message div is created within the form tag; I want the message div out of the form tag. Below are codes in use;

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
// newsletter

    (function(){

        var subscribe = $('#subscribe');
        subscribe.append('<div class="message_container_subscribe"></div>');
        var message = $('.message_container_subscribe'),text;

        subscribe.on('submit',function(e){
            var self = $(this);

            if(self.find('input[type="email"]').val() == ''){
                text = "Please enter your e-mail!";
                message.html('<div class="alert_box color_red r_corners error"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i> '+text+'</div>')
                    .slideDown()
                    .delay(4000)
                    .slideUp(function(){
                        $(this).html("");
                    });

            }else{
                self.find('span.error').hide();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "newsletter.php",
                    data: self.serialize(), 
                    success: function(data){
                        if(data == 1){
                            text = "Your email has been sent successfully!";
                            message.html('<div class="alert_box r_corners color_green success"><i class="fa fa-check-square"></i> '+text+'</div>')
                                .slideDown()
                                .delay(4000)
                                .slideUp(function(){
                                    $(this).html("");
                                })
                                .prevAll('input[type="email"]').val("");
                        }else{
                            text = "Invalid email address!";
                            message.html('<div class="alert_box color_red r_corners error"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i><p>'+text+'</p></div>')
                                .slideDown()
                                .delay(4000)
                                .slideUp(function(){
                                    $(this).html("");
                                });
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            e.preventDefault();
        });

    })();
```

**HTML**

```
<form action="newsletter.php" method="post" name="subscribe-form" id="subscribe" class="subscribe-form">
                    <input type="email" placeholder="Your email address" id="emailnews" class="email" name="emailnews">
                    <button type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit">Subscribe</button>
                </form>
```

[**SNAPSHOT FROM CODE INSPECT IN CHROME**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/urx5B.jpg)

Comment: So why don't you just put it outside the form then?

Comment: Hi, but i don't see any such divs in the html form. It is injected via the javascript and I am not able to find the way out. Thanks.

Comment: Append it to a different element outside the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [jQuery after()](http://api.jquery.com/after/) instead of `append`. Like this:

`$("form").after('<div class="message_container_subscribe"></div>');`

```js
// newsletter

    (function(){

        var subscribe = $('#subscribe');
        $("form").after('<div class="message_container_subscribe"></div>');
        var message = $('.message_container_subscribe'),text;

        subscribe.on('submit',function(e){
            var self = $(this);

            if(self.find('input[type="email"]').val() == ''){
                text = "Please enter your e-mail!";
                message.html('<div class="alert_box color_red r_corners error"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i> '+text+'</div>')
                    .slideDown()
                    .delay(140000)
                    .slideUp(function(){
                        $(this).html("");
                    });

            }else{
                self.find('span.error').hide();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "newsletter.php",
                    data: self.serialize(), 
                    success: function(data){
                        if(data == 1){
                            text = "Your email has been sent successfully!";
                            message.html('<div class="alert_box r_corners color_green success"><i class="fa fa-check-square"></i> '+text+'</div>')
                                .slideDown()
                                .delay(4000)
                                .slideUp(function(){
                                    $(this).html("");
                                })
                                .prevAll('input[type="email"]').val("");
                        }else{
                            text = "Invalid email address!";
                            message.html('<div class="alert_box color_red r_corners error"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i><p>'+text+'</p></div>')
                                .slideDown()
                                .delay(4000)
                                .slideUp(function(){
                                    $(this).html("");
                                });
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            e.preventDefault();
        });

    })();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="newsletter.php" method="post" name="subscribe-form" id="subscribe" class="subscribe-form">
                    <input type="email" placeholder="Your email address" id="emailnews" class="email" name="emailnews">
                    <button type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit">Subscribe</button>
                </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use div outside of form and edit your js code like

```
(".message_container_subscribe").html("Your Message Here")
```

Use this where u want 
Hope this working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your alert message div is now appended inside the form with the following line:

```
subscribe.append('<div class="message_container_subscribe"></div>');
```

You can simply create the alert div outside the form by setting the following:

```
 subscribe.after('<div class="message_container_subscribe"></div>');
```

Now the alert message div is outside the form and the rest of the stuff will work as it is and the message will be shown outside the form.

Comment: Yeah, np. I see somebody got to it before me, but my answer only altered one word ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('<div class="alert_box color_red r_corners error"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i><p>'+text+'</p></div>').insertAfter($('#subscribe'));
```